# whileTap and whileHover props do not work as expected on elements inside an iFrame

Tags: reactjs, iframe, framer-motion

Reacts `framer-motion` whileTap and whileHover props do not work as expected on elements inside an iFrame. Here is a sandbox demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/d3rku

In Chrome and Safari whileHover does not work at all, and whileTap does half of the animation. In Firefox, whileHover works but whileTap does not.
Seems like mouse events are not propagated properly inside the iFrame. I've noticed this with some other libraries too, when I render them with react inside the iFrame.